# Export panda dataframe to CSV

Tags: pandas, dataframe, export-to-csv

I have a code where at the end I export a dataframe in CSV format. However each time I run my code it replaces the previous CSV while I would like to accumulate my csv files
Do you now a method to do this ?

```
dfind.to_csv(r'C:\Users\StageProject\Indicateurs\indStat.csv', index = True, header=True)
```

Thanks !

Comment: I guess changing name of the csv file is the only option

Comment: I know this option but it's not very practical ...

Answer (score 1):

The question is really about how you want to name your files. The easiest way is just to attach a timestamp to each one:

```
import time
unix_time = round(time.time())
```

This should be unique under most real-world conditions because time doesn't go backwards and Python will give `time.time()` only in UTC. Then just save to the path:

```
rf'C:\Users\StageProject\Indicateurs\indStat_{unix_time}.csv'
```

If you want to do a serial count, like what your browser does when you save multiple versions, you will need to iterate through the files in that folder and then keep adding one to your suffix until you get to a file path that does not conflict, then save thereto.